# How to check if two integer-valued polynomials have a common power?

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, algorithms, sagemath

Let $p, q \in \mathbb{Z}[x]$ be two integer-valued polynomial. **Is there a (hopefully efficient) algorithm that checks whether $p^n = q^m$ for some $n,m \geq 1$?**

I need such an algorithm for a program I have to write, but it seems that there isn't much information on the internet.

An idea is to take the leading coefficients $a$ and $b$ of $p$ and $q$ and then note that $p^n = q^m$ implies that $a^n = b^m$. The last equation can be solved using prime decompositions, and also gives that the set of solutions pairs (if any) are of the form $(k n_0, km_0)$, where $n_0, m_0 \geq 1$ are fixed and $k \geq 1$. Continuing with an inductive argument may work?

Comment: The approach you describe is the one I would have taken.

Comment: You can solve this problem in $\mathbb{Q}\left[x\right]$; the integrality doesn't really matter. Use the UFDness of $\mathbb{Q}\left[x\right]$ to argue that $p^n = q^m$ is equivalent to $p$ and $q$ have the same radical (= squarefree part). But this is easy to check by just computing the radicals of $p$ and $q$, for which there is a simple method: To find the radical of $f$, divide $f$ by $\gcd\left(f,f'\right)$; rinse and repeat, until the gcd becomes $1$. OK, you'll have to check that the constant terms match at the end, but this is an easy integer problem.

Comment: @darijgrinberg: I don't think that's right. $x^2(x-1)$ and $x(x-1)^2$ have the same radical, $x(x-1)$, but they don't have a common power.

Comment: If the radicals match, we can check raising the common radical to appropriate degrees obtains monic multiples of $p,\,q$. This only happens if the radical's degree divides $\gcd(\deg p,\,\deg q)$.

Comment: If $p^n=q^m$, then $a^n=b^m$, as you say; but we also have $n\deg p=m\deg q$. Not very useful in finding $n,m$, but it does rule out many pairs $p,q$ that have no common power.

Comment: Ah right, thanks @TonyK for finding this and JG for the fix!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As TonyK mentioned in the comments, $p^n = q^m$ implies $n\deg p = m \deg q$, so $\frac{n}{m} = \frac{\deg q}{\deg p}$.

This means we can scale the exponents in the equation $p^n = q^m$ by raising to powers and/or taking roots of both sides to obtain

$$p^{\deg q} = \pm q^{\deg p} \tag{$*$}$$

where the $\pm$ comes from potentially taking an even root. So just compute both sides of $(*)$ and check if they're equal up to sign.

---

But, we can do better!

Raising polynomials to large powers is computationally expensive, so let's find a faster method.

Take the logarithmic derivative of both sides of $(*)$:

$$ \deg q \cdot \frac{p'}{p} = \deg p \cdot\frac{q'}{q}, $$

i.e.

$$ (\deg{q})\cdot p' q = (\deg{p}) \cdot q' p. \tag{$\dagger$}$$

So if $p^n = q^m$ for some $n$ and $m$, then $(\dagger)$ must hold, though the reverse is not necessarily true.

Reversing the steps, we see that if $(\dagger)$ is true, then $p^{\deg q} = C\cdot q^{\deg p}$ for some constant $C$. We want $C$ to be $\pm 1$; we can check if this is true from the leading coefficients $a$ and $b$. So we should have

$$a^{\deg q} = \pm b^{\deg p}. \tag{$\ddagger$}$$

In summary, $p^n = q^m$ for some $m$ and $n$ if and only if both $(\dagger)$ and $(\ddagger)$ hold.

Comment: Taking logarithmic derivates like that, it's a nice trick!